# Why is Hamiltonian Path and graph coloring np complete and shortest path p when the former can also be solved using DFS recursively?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, shortest-path, hamiltonian-path

NP is a complexity class that represents the set of all decision problems for which the instances where the answer is "yes" have proofs that can be verified in polynomial time. But hamiltonian path can also be deduced by recursively traversing dfs.

Comment: How do you solve Hamiltonian path using a DFS?

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-paths-given-source-destination/          ..... Use it and check whether the path covers all vertices.

Comment: @UlsaMinor And what if it doesn't cover all the vertices?

Comment: then their is no hamiltonian path available!

Comment: @UslaMinor But maybe there is *another* path that covers all the vertices? You've checked only one possible path.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "deduced by recursively traversing dfs" but the depth-first search tree is, in general, exponentially large in the size of the graph so any algorithm that potentially involves looking at all of it must take exponential time in the worst case.

Indeed, it's not even obvious that you can solve Hamiltonian path using depth-first search. Consider the graph that is a clique plus one extra vertex, which sends one edge to the clique, say to vertex $x$. If you start your depth-first search at $x$, none of the paths explored by the DFS will be Hamiltonian. Further, if you start at any other vertex in the clique, you might have to explore something like $n!$ paths before you find a path that visits every vertex in the clique, finishing at $x$ and then moves to the extra vertex.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by depth-first search tree. I know it as the tree produced by DFS. That has the same size as the graph.

Comment: Look at the above link and tell me why you can't use the above and change it a bit to check whether it is hamiltonian path just by adding one case and that is when all the vertices are touched?

Comment: @UlsaMinor you can do that, but it takes exponential time to check all paths.

Comment: Okay fine, got it. But how do you get the running time for it in exponent?

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret the question correctly, it asks whether you could solve Hamiltonian Path by performing depth first search and checking whether the tree that describes the search is in fact a path that includes all vertexes.

Consider this graph:

```
      C
     / \
A---B---D---E
```

There is a Hamiltonian Path in this graph: ABCDE.

Depth-first search, starting from A, may result in a tree

```
A-B-C-D-E
```

that is the Hamiltonian Path.

But, depending the order in which it considers adjacent vertexes while searching, it may instead result in the tree

```
A-B-D-E
     \
      C
```

This does not reveal that there is a Hamiltonian path.

The trouble with using depth-first search to solve Hamiltonian Path is that you have to re-run the search for each possible vertex ordering, and that requires exponential time.